# Redirect to external link on Image click Magento

Tags: magento, redirect, magento-1.5

I have created a static block in my home page and inserted a image in it. To that image I am using a anchor tag so that it will redirect to another link.

But actually its not working for me.My website domain is www.openerpengines.com and on the image click, it should be redirected to openerpengines.com:8069 . I am stuck up in this little problem. Please help me out.

I am providing us my Website link: www.openerpengines.com

Answer (score 3):

I have found the solution.

I have used onclick function in the image tag. the code follows as:

```
<img src"image path" onclick="window.location.href='URL to redirect';"/>
```